# Catch file download events in Electron app

Tags: javascript, download, electron

I'm writing a wrapper desktop application around a webpage using Electron. I'm using a [`<webview>`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md) control to display the page. Noticed that if i click on a link which result in a file download in a normal browser (the HTTP response has `Content-Disposition` header) does nothing in Electron, which is fine by me since i like to control what happens to downloaded files. The app will run in a restricted environment.

Can't seem to figure out how can i catch the download event. There is the [`did-get-response-details`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#did-get-response-details) event which gets fired when i click on the link, but i can't access any response data (at least the headers), nor it states that Electron will not handle this link so i can do whatever i want to do with it on my own, like fetching it with the node.js API.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/atom/electron/pull/1386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response headers are available in the mentioned event as soon as this patch gets merged: https://github.com/atom/electron/pull/1604 After that downloads can be caught by checking for the `Content-Disposition` header.